# How to incease the value of particular cell in a table by adding value to it as provided by text box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

help me in following issue of Vb.net
I have two tables **"Purchase"** and Other one **"stocklevel"** each table has **three columns**

**Purchase**

ID, Item, Qt

**stocklevel**

ID , Item , Level

( ID is a Primary Key in table **stocklevel**)

and what i want is when I save value to purchase table which are received from input boxes (as entered by user) ,I want the value present in "Qt" colume of table "purchase" is added to the cell of column "level" of table "stocklevel" and this is to be done by checking the ID

I have put following code but not working

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Me.Validate()
    PurchaseBindingSource.EndEdit()
    PurchaseTableAdapter.Update(TwoDataSet.Purchase)

    '------------
    strsql = "select * from stocklevel where ID = '" & IDTextBox.Text & "'"


    Dim acscmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    acscmd.CommandText = strsql
    acscmd.Connection = acsconn


    '====================================================================
    ‘Creating a New connection to Table named  stocklevel

    If Not acsconn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        acsconn.Open()
    End If
        Try

        Dim strsql2 As String = "" & _
       "UPDATE stocklevel SET level= level + "( & (Val(QtTextBox.Text) &) " where [ID]='" & IDtextbox.Text"'"


        Dim acscmd2 As New OleDbCommand
        acscmd2.Connection = acsconn
        acscmd2.CommandText = strsql2
        acscmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
    Finally
        acsconn.Close()


    End Try
   acscmd.Dispose()
   acscmd2.Dispose()
```

End Sub

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: `but not working` is a terrible problem description.  it tells us nothing.  Please read [ask] and take  the [tour].  And always use SQL parameters.  Always.

Comment: hello there sorry for inconvience ,as it my 1st in this website and also I am a begainer

Comment: hello there, sorry for inconvience ,as it my 1st day in this website and also I am a begainer in vb.net , my Question is very simple  I have two table namely "Purchase" and "stocklevel" , in purchase table I have 3 colums  ID ,Item , Qt in the same way I have 3 colums in table "stock level" which are ID, Item, Level  and what i want is when I save value to purchase table which are received from input boxes (as entered by user) ,I want the value present in "Qt" colume of table "purchase"  is added to the cell of column "level"  of table "stocklevel" and  this is to be done by checking the ID

Comment: Thanks in advance